# Prism.unity.forms,How to dependency injection in contentview's viewmodel?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, inversion-of-control, prism

My project using prism

[image: imamge1]

I register service 'IHomePageService' in app.xaml.cs

[image: image2]

My 'About' view,this is '**ContentView**'

[image: image3]

My "AboutViewModel" binding 'About' View, I try to DI 'IHomePageService' in 'AboutViewModel' Constructor

[image: image4]

When I debug,thrown an exception

[image: image5]

When I DI "IHomePageService" in "HomePageViewModel(Binding HomePage,this is **ContentPage**)" Constructor ,everything is OK.

## IS DI only use ViewModel Binding with ContentPage?

ADD sample:https://github.com/ouzs/PrismTestProj

Comment: Please edit your post and put the code in the question body.

Comment: Please post a sample project. It appears that you have set the Autowire property on your `About` View, so that should work, but it's hard to see exactly what your issue is without a sample that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: [stackoverflow.com/tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), *How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*: [stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and *How to Ask Good Questions* [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code that you've tried showing effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Please don't use screenshot. Instead post code so it can be copied easily. There are ways to embed code with indentation and styling (colors) in StackOverflow.